# Node-Server wrong directory in loading Template via Express

Tags: node.js, ejs, dirname

I have some problems when running my Node-Server on Remote via an Service.
I get the following Error:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory
>   "/home/naoufal/etc/run-nodeServer/views"  at EventEmitter.render
>   (/var/www/virtual/naoufal/html/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)

He looks for my Templatefolder in the path, where the Servicescript is started, namely (/home/naoufal/etc/run-nodeServer/...)
My Node-Application is on (~/html/...).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ECT = require('ect');
var ectRenderer = ECT({watch: true, root: __dirname + '/views',ext: '.ect'});

app.set('view engine','ect');
app.engine('ect',ectRenderer.render);

app.get('/',function(req, res){
res.render('index');
  });
app.listen(68000);
```

I tried instead of ('__dirname + '/views')
This '/home/naoufal/html/views' but the same error occurs...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

ok I found the solution:

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){
res.render('index');
});
```

Here he did not use the right Path, from the Renderer. I don't know why? Instead it takes the path of the executing script...

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){
res.render(__dirname + '/views/index');
});
```

solved the problem anyway.